# Documenting mongoose model methods with jsdoc

Tags: mongoose, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm trying to document mongoose model methods with jsdoc. A model's method belongs to the model, thus I would like to see it as it's member method.

The file contains a top level `@module models` line as well.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var MySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

/**
 * My method
 *
 * @function myMethod
 * @memberof MySchema
 * @this MySchema
 * @param {ObjectId} object
 * @params {Array} roles, defaults to all
 * @returns Participant or null
 */
 MySchema.method('myMethod', function(object, roles) {
   // ...
 });
```

Currently I receive a module page that contains a link to my class definition, and a page documenting the class definition, but the method does not appear on any of these pages. When I remove `@memberof`, then the method appears on the module page. I would like to have it on the class page though.

What part of the jsdoc docs am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be explicit about the module:

```
@memberof module:models~MySchema
```

The fact is that jsdoc is not going to infer that when you specify `MySchema` you mean the `MySchema` entity which is *in the current module*.

Same with `@this`, actually. If you modify it to have the module name, then in the documentation the part about `this` will have a link to the definition of `MySchema`.

Comment: I also had to add `@instance` as a tag or it thought my method was static.